# Functions, variables in functions, and tighter coding practices

Tags: powershell

I'm not totally new to powershell, it's just that my scripts have been getting more complex and some concepts elude me.  My scripts seem overly long because I use a lot of functions with repeatable pieces.  It seems like I could do variables somewhere in my functions but I really don't understand where to start (and I've been searching).

This script formats and labels disks based on the number of disks added to a Windows virtual machine (2k8r2).  I use a lot of functions (and the script works...which is usually where I stop)... it's just that I'm just trying to improve my scripting abilities.  So the big question is how do I shorten this up?  Is there a better way to lay out and write my code?  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks

```
#Powershell script to pull info from diskpart and format disks
#Date      : 09/15/2014

Function DISKFORMAT
{NEW-ITEM -Name detail.txt -ItemType file -force | OUT-NULL
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "SELECT DISK $DISKID"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "FORMAT FS=NTFS QUICK"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "ASSIGN"
$DETAIL=(DISKPART /S detail.txt)}

Function SQLDIR1
{New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL -ItemType directory
New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL\DATA01 -ItemType directory
New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL\TRANS01 -ItemType directory
New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL\LOG01 -ItemType directory
New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL\TEMPDB -ItemType directory}

Function SQLDIR2
{New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL -ItemType directory
New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL\DATA01 -ItemType directory
New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL\TRANS01 -ItemType directory
New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL\LOG01 -ItemType directory
New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL\TEMPDB -ItemType directory
New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL\Backup -ItemType directory}

Function SQLDATA01
{NEW-ITEM -Name detail.txt -ItemType file -force | OUT-NULL
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "SELECT DISK $DISKID"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "FORMAT FS=NTFS UNIT=64K QUICK"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "ASSIGN MOUNT=D:\MSSQL\DATA01"}

Function SQLTRANS01
{NEW-ITEM -Name detail.txt -ItemType file -force | OUT-NULL
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "SELECT DISK $DISKID"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "FORMAT FS=NTFS UNIT=64K QUICK"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "ASSIGN MOUNT=D:\MSSQL\TRANS01"}

Function SQLLOG01
{NEW-ITEM -Name detail.txt -ItemType file -force | OUT-NULL
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "SELECT DISK $DISKID"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "FORMAT FS=NTFS UNIT=64K QUICK"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "ASSIGN MOUNT=D:\MSSQL\LOG01"}

Function SQLTEMPDB
{NEW-ITEM -Name detail.txt -ItemType file -force | OUT-NULL
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "SELECT DISK $DISKID"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "FORMAT FS=NTFS UNIT=64K QUICK"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "ASSIGN MOUNT=D:\MSSQL\TEMPDB"}

Function SQLBACKUP
{NEW-ITEM -Name detail.txt -ItemType file -force | OUT-NULL
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "SELECT DISK $DISKID"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "FORMAT FS=NTFS UNIT=64K QUICK"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "ASSIGN MOUNT=D:\MSSQL\Backup"}

Function LABEL1
{$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'"
    Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="C:"; Label="OS"}}

Function LABEL2
{$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'"
    Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="C:"; Label="OS"}
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'D:'"
    Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="D:"; Label="Data"}}

Function LABEL3
{$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'"
    Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="C:"; Label="OS"}
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'D:'"
    Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="D:"; Label="Apps"}
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'E:'"
    Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="E:"; Label="Data"}}

Function LABEL4
{$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'"
    Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="C:"; Label="OS"}
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'D:'"
    Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="D:"; Label="Apps"}
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'E:'"
    Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="E:"; Label="Data"}
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'F:'"
    Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="F:"; Label="Data01"}}

# List All disks
NEW-ITEM –name listdisk.txt –itemtype file –force | OUT-NULL
ADD-CONTENT –path listdisk.txt "LIST DISK"
$LISTDISK=(DISKPART /S listdisk.txt)
$TOTALDISK=($LISTDISK.Count)-7

#If there's only one disk (OS DISK) Exit the script
IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 1)
{LABEL1}

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 2)
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
LABEL2}

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 3)
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[9].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
LABEL3}

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 4)
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[9].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[10].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
LABEL4}

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 5)
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
LABEL2
SQLDIR1
SQLDATA01
SQLTRANS01
SQLLOG01
SQLTEMPDB}

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 6)
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
LABEL2
SQLDIR2
SQLDATA01
SQLTRANS01
SQLLOG01
SQLTEMPDB
SQLBACKUP}


ELSE {EXIT}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SQLTEMPDB** and similar functions.

For starters I know that you can cosolidate the functions like this since the only thing that changes is the path.

```
Function SQLTEMPDB
{NEW-ITEM -Name detail.txt -ItemType file -force | OUT-NULL
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "SELECT DISK $DISKID"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "FORMAT FS=NTFS UNIT=64K QUICK"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "ASSIGN MOUNT=D:\MSSQL\TEMPDB"}
```

Using a parameter for the path you could change it to this to reduce it to one function. Also reduce the calls to `Add-Content` down to one. User a Here-String and add a path to it as the need fits.

```
Function Add-FormatDetail{
param($Path)
NEW-ITEM -Name detail.txt -ItemType file -force | OUT-NULL
$details = @"
SELECT DISK $DISKID
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
FORMAT FS=NTFS UNIT=64K QUICK
ASSIGN MOUNT=$Path
"@
Add-Content -Path detail.txt -Value $details
}
```

For example instead of called `SQLTEMPDB` you would call the following

```
Add-FormatDetail -Path "D:\MSSQL\TEMPDB"
```

**Label** function could also be consolidated. A simple ( by no means elegant ) solution would be again to make a single function that takes a $driveCount as a parameter.

```
Function Update-DriveLabels{
    param([int]$driveCount)
    If ($driveCount -gt 0){
        $drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'"
            Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="C:"; Label="OS"}
    }
    If ($driveCount -gt 1){
        $drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'D:'"
            Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="D:"; Label="Apps"}
    }
    If ($driveCount -gt 2){
        $drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'E:'"
            Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="E:"; Label="Data"}
    }
    If ($driveCount -gt 3){
    $drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'F:'"
        Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="F:"; Label="Data01"}
    }
}
```

So the call would be in your script

```
Update-DriveLabels -DriveCount $TOTALDISK
```

Comment: Thanks so much as it helps me understand the concept better.  I realized after I tested the script I wasn't labeling the disks for SQL and that makes SQL admins unhappy.  

So how do I make the param path = d:\mssql\ so I can use the variable in the label look like this:
FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL=$PATH UNIT=64K QUICK

Actually, since I'm using the d:\mssql\ in the directory creation, can't I set a global variable?

Comment: If I get what you are saying after the `param` keyword you could just add a line that says `$path = "d:\mssql\$path"` which would add `d:\mssql\` in front of every path?

Comment: I just used a global variable since I was calling that directory multiple times.

Comment: Then when you call the function `Add-FormatDetail` just use your global in the `-path`. `Add-FormatDetail -Path "$SqlPath\TEMPDB"` for example.

Comment: I posted the final working (tested) version.  There's only one minor issue with the label portion throwing errors...but it works like a charm.  Tested it with multiple disk configs.  Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to avoid command repetition use as below.

```
New-Item -Path D:\MSSQL,D:\MSSQL\DATA01,D:\MSSQL\TRANS01,D:\MSSQL\LOG01,D:\MSSQL\TEMPDB -ItemType directory
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "SELECT DISK $DISKID", "CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY","FORMAT FS=NTFS UNIT=64K QUICK","ASSIGN MOUNT=D:\MSSQL\Backup"
```

This will shrink your script.

Functionality of LABEL1 is repeated in LABEL2, LABEL3, etc...

you can write it as

```
Function LABEL1
{
Operation1
}

Function LABEL2
{
;call LABEL1
Operation2
}

Function LABEL3
{
; call LABEL2
Operation3
}
```

No need to create function if it is not getting used more than once. Make it sequential script and divide in sections using comments. 
Or write functions with parameters and take actions depending some input parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the 2nd part regarding labels.  Are those still functions?

Comment: LABEL2 and LABEL3 is executing same command in LABEL, so instead you can call function LABEL1 in LABEL2. Similarly for function LABEL3

Answer (score 0):

@Matt Thanks for your comment it was very helpful.

There's only one minor issue.  In the label section if there's no disk it errors out.  Should I ELSE exit or is there some better way of doing it?

This is the final working script (EDIT: updated the script after a request from SQL team for an additional configuration):

```
#set the path variable
$folder="D:\MSSQL\"

#Function to Format Disks using diskpart
Function DISKFORMAT
{NEW-ITEM -Name detail.txt -ItemType file -force | OUT-NULL
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "SELECT DISK $DISKID"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "FORMAT FS=NTFS QUICK"
ADD-CONTENT -Path detail.txt "ASSIGN"
$DETAIL=(DISKPART /S detail.txt)}

#Function to format disks for SQL
Function Add-FormatDetail{
param($Path)
NEW-ITEM -Name detail1.txt -ItemType file -force | OUT-NULL
$details = @"
SELECT DISK $DISKID
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL=$Path UNIT=64K QUICK
ASSIGN MOUNT=$Folder$Path
"@
Add-Content -Path detail1.txt -Value $details
$DETAIL=(DISKPART /S detail1.txt)}

#Function to automatically label all disks other than SQL
Function Update-DriveLabels{
    param([int]$driveCount)
    If ($driveCount -gt 0){
        $drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'"
            Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="C:"; Label="OS"}
    }
    If ($driveCount -gt 1){
        $drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'D:'"
            Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="D:"; Label="Apps"}
    }
    If ($driveCount -gt 2){
        $drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'E:'"
            Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="E:"; Label="Data"}
    }
    If ($driveCount -gt 3){
    $drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'F:'"
        Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="F:"; Label="Data01"}
    }
} 

# List All disks
NEW-ITEM –name listdisk.txt –itemtype file –force | OUT-NULL
ADD-CONTENT –path listdisk.txt "LIST DISK"
$LISTDISK=(DISKPART /S listdisk.txt)
$TOTALDISK=($LISTDISK.Count)-7

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 2)
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT}

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 3) 
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[9].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT}

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 4) 
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[9].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[10].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT}

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 5) 
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[9].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[10].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[11].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT}

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 6) 
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT 
New-Item -Path $folder,$folder"DATA01",$folder"TRANS01",$folder"TEMPDB",$folder"Backup" -ItemType directory
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[9].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "DATA01"
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[10].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "TRANS01"
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[11].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "TEMPDB"
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[12].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "Backup"}

IF ($TOTALDISK -eq 10) 
{$DISKID=$LISTDISK[8].substring(7,5).trim()
DISKFORMAT 
New-Item -Path $folder,$folder"DATA01",$folder"TRANS01",$folder"TEMPDB",$folder"Backup" -ItemType directory
New-Item -Path $folder"DATA02",$folder"TRANS02",$folder"TEMPDB2",$folder"Backup2" -ItemType directory
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[9].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "DATA01"
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[10].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "TRANS01"
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[11].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "TEMPDB"
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[12].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "Backup"
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[13].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "DATA02"
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[14].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "TRANS02"
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[15].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "TEMPDB2"
$DISKID=$LISTDISK[16].substring(7,5).trim()
Add-FormatDetail -Path "Backup2"}

Update-DriveLabels -DriveCount $TOTALDISK
```

Comment: I would need to know what the error is to be sure. Even if the number of drives was $null it should cast to `[int]` as `0`. With anything you should always put the exact error your getting.

Comment: 'Set-WmiInstance : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\temp\diskform.ps1:44 char:36
+             Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="E:"; Label=" ...
+                                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-WmiInstance], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetWmiInsta
   nce'

Comment: Basically, if there isn't a drive count greater than x, the script should exit.  Currently, it throws a non-fatal error  on all drives greater than x.  So if there's only 1 extra disk, the script will error on 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: What was the value of $drivecount when the error occurred. It might just be late but i'm having an issue with what the problem is

Comment: @Matt In this case, the drivecount was -gt 2 so it produced the error on the -gt 2 and -gt 3. In this test, there were only 2 disks so -gt 0 and -gt 1 labeled properly and threw an error on the last 2 because those disks didn't exist.

Comment: If there were only 2 disks then `$driveCount -gt 2` would be false and not execute. Curious